# How do I Launch an Applescript with a Hotkey Without Automator?

Tags: keyboard, terminal, applescript, macos

I'm running Yosemite and looking to launch Terminal with a keypress in any application. One solution was creating a Service in Automator that launched terminal and assigning a key to it in System Preferences. However there is an annoying delay before launching Automator services, I'd like something immediate. Is there a way to do as such, preferably without installing software that runs in the background?

Answer (score 1):

I found Automator's "Launch Application" action to be as quick as anything else, and the only way to do this without third party software.

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) is a free application that can be used to launch applications using hotkeys.

[iTerm 2](https://www.iterm2.com/) is a Terminal.app replacement that can be shown/hidden using a hotkey (if it's running).